# Common density function - which is the value of $C$ ?

Tags: probability, density-function

The random variables $X,Y$ get only non-negative integer values and have common density function $f(m,n)=C\cdot (0.2)^m\cdot (0.3)^n$, for $m,n\geq 0$.

To calculate the value of $C$ we consider the property $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(m,n)\, dm\, dn=1$$ ? And since $m,n\geq 0$ do we get $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(m,n)\, dm\, dn=1$$ ?

Comment: I would use  sums rather than integrals since $X,Y$ are integers.

Comment: Ah you mean $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(m,n)=1$$ ? @callculus

Comment: Yes, that I´ve meant.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-) @callculus

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to find the value of $C$ we evaluate the cdf

$$ f(m,n) = C \cdot (0.2)^{m} \cdot (0.3)^{n} |  m,n  \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}$$

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(m ,n ) =1  \tag{2}$$

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  C \cdot (0.2)^{m} \cdot (0.3)^{n}  \tag{3}$$
We can rewrite this. This is a geometric series.
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5^{m}}  = 1 + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{25} + \cdots  \tag{4}$$

The geometric series formula is 
$$ 1+ r + r^{2} + r^{3} + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-r}  \tag{5}$$

$ \textrm{ Let } r =\frac{1}{5} \tag{6}$
$$ \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}= \frac{1}{\frac{4}{5}} = \frac{5}{4} = 1.25 \tag{7}$$

The following is the same as above

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{3}{10})^{n} = 1  + \frac{3}{10} + \frac{9}{100} + \cdots   \tag{8}$$
$$ \textrm{ Let } r = \frac{3}{10} \tag{9} $$
$$ \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{10}} = \frac{1}{\frac{7}{10}} =\frac{10}{7} \tag{10}$$

Then we get

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  f(m,n) = C \frac{5}{4} \frac{10}{7} = C \cdot 1.\overline{7857142}  \tag{11}$$

Then you see that $C$ is simply the reciprocal

$$ C = \frac{4}{5} \frac{7}{10} = \frac{28}{50} = \frac{14}{25}\tag{12}$$

Then we find that $f(m,n)$ is

$$ f(m,n) = \frac{14}{25}(0.2)^{m}(0.3)^{n} | m ,n \in \mathbb{N}  \tag{13}$$

you can confirm with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=14%2F25%20sum%20m%3D0%20to%20infty%20sum%20n%3D0%20to%20infty%20(0.2)%5Em(0.3)%5En)

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: @MaryStar I thought you could do it by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I had already calculated the value of C before I got that answer, thanks to your comment that I have to use the sum instead of the integral in this case! @callculus